# Best flash upload widget

Tags: flash, actionscript, upload, widget

I'm looking to upgrade the upload function of a web app of mine from a fairly simple PHP + javascript uploader to a flash uploader.  I've been looking into swfupload  from swfupload.org.  I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with that library, or if someone can recommend a good pre-built flash upload widget.  I don't mind if it requires some custom code to get running as long as it works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/ - easy to implement, easy to customize, multiple uploads.

Comment: Thanks!  This one looks a lot like swfupload, but simpler to implement

Answer (score 3):

I know your looking for a flash-based widget, but I can't say enough about the java based [jUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/).  It is extremely customizable, can chunk-split files to bypass your `max_upload_filesize` limitations, and can handle multiple files at once.  Also has the ability to use the client's native file-picker.  Plus it's open-source, which is always  plus.

Comment: Right on, I'll check it out.  I'm not opposed to using a java uploader, as long as it's simple for users to upload with, and it's reliable.  Thanks for the prompt response!